# Standard weight conversions for converting cups of flour to grams of flour?

Tags: baking, flour, measurements, conversion

I hate the idea of measuring flour using something as imprecise as measuring scoop.

What numbers do you treat as definitive/authoritative/canonical for doing weight conversions for different types of flour?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no official standard.  The USDA uses 125g/cup, but labels on packages claim different weights for one cup:

- Gold Medal brand: 130g
- King Arthur brand: 120g (updated 2016)
- [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1+cup+of+white+flour): 137g
- superpacked: 165g

I always convert my recipes to weights using 140g/cup.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned [in this related question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/2321/cup-measurements-shake-or-scrape), if you have a recipe in cups and want to use weight, you'd have to know how the person who developed the recipe did it: i.e. did they sift if and then gently scoop it into the cup and scrape it off?

[This answer from that question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/2321/cup-measurements-shake-or-scrape/2459#2459), matches my experience: one cup is about 4oz.

Answer (score 3):

I do not think there is any standard table you can trust for something as simple as "a cup of flour."   Each type (AP, whole wheat, bread, etc.) has a particular weight defined by the mill or the recipe writer.  You need to know how that recipe source defines it and what brand they are using.  Few authors are kind enough to provide this in the instructions.  You can find tables that claim to provide the conversion you are requesting but you will likely find that the tables only work with the recipes by that author.  Using recipes that fail to provide weights forces you to judge the dough by feel.