# How much does a dL of flour weigh?

Tags: baking, measurements

I have a baking recipe that uses metric volume measurements. I’d like to convert deciliters to weight.

How much does a deciliter of flour weigh?

Comment: We already have different questions for converting flour volume to weight, maybe the most canonical one is https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/2915/standard-weight-conversions-for-converting-cups-of-flour-to-grams-of-flour. I still hesitate to close this one as a duplicate, especially because most people in the world are not aware that a "cup" is a standardized measurement of volume, so for them, an answer about the conversion of cups to weight is not useful.

Comment: where is this recipe that is using metric volume of flour?

Answer (score 4):

There can be no exact general conversion because flour's density depends on how it has packed into a space and also a little on the specific flour – this is why mass measurements are preferred for most serious purposes.

However, there are plenty of resources that will give you a suitable answer and any recipe using volume measurements for solids shouldn't be too dependent on small variations: the first one that came up for me when I googled 'dl flour in grams' was [this](https://convertunits.online/food-conversion/flour/flour-dl-to-grams/1-dl-deciliter-flour-to-grams/) which gives **52.1g**. (The implied level of precision here is misleading of course.)

Comment: This is pretty close to the rule of thumb I learned which is that flour has a density of around 0.5 (g/cm^3 or kg/l).

Comment: @quarague Nice rule of thumb!

Answer (score 0):

Building off what @dbmag9 said:

According to [Pastries like a pro](https://pastrieslikeapro.com/2013/05/ingredient-conversion-chart/)

- 1 Cup Sifted Flour ~114g, so 1 dL is about 48g.
- 1 Cup Unsifted Flour ~140g, so 1dL is about 59g.

So, if it is "Sifted Flour" or "Flour, Sifted", you would have different weights.

I also looked at [King Arthur Baking](https://www.kingarthurbaking.com/learn/ingredient-weight-chart) for "flour".

- Averaging the Wheat flours came out to about 50.55g / 1dL.
- All Purpose flour came out to 50.7g / dL.
- Averaging all 48 types of "flour" listed came out to 47.18g/dL.

Answer (score -1):

> dL (deciliter = 0.10 liter [100ml] = 100g of water)

'dL' is used in Sweden as a measuring spoon/cup and 60g is quoted for flour.

---

Translated from **Umrechnung dl = g** page listed below:

| name | dL |
| --- | --- |
| Sugar | 90g |
| Flour | 60g |
| Fine rye flour | 50g |
| table salt | 121.7g |
| Coarse rye flour | 55g |
| food starch | 80g |
| Syrup or Honey | 140g |
| Almonds/Nuts | 65g |
| raisins | 60g |
| Melted butter | 90g |
| oatmeal | 30g |

For those who are not in Sweden, IKEA seems to offer such spoons/cups:

[VARDAGEN](https://www.ikea.com/de/de/p/vardagen-kuechenmass-5er-satz-60324723):

- 1 ml (1 [Swedish] pinch = **density g/ml**)

  - table salt = 1.217g

    - 1 Cup (US) = 287.9278838205g=((1.217*0.2365882365)*1000)

      - 1/16 Teaspoon, pinch (US) = 0.3749060987g
- 1 Teaspoon. (5ml)
- 1 Tablespoon (15ml)
- 1/2 Deciliter (50ml)
- 1 Deciliter (100ml) = 0.4226752838 Cup (US)

  - 1 Cup (US) = 2.365882365 dL = 236.5882365ml of water

    - 100ml=236.5882365*0.4226752838

If you know that your flour is 140g per US Cup:

- 1 dL = 59.1745397282g = 140/2.365882365
  [image]

---

**Sources**:

- [Swedish Baking Measurements and Measures](https://www.klefstadpublishing.com/measures.asp)
- [Umrechnung dl = g](https://www.winterkurier.se/umrechnung-dl-g/) (in German)
- [tsk, msk und dl: Schwedische Maßeinheiten | TROLLLAND](https://trollland.eu/schwedische-masseinheiten/) (in German)
- [VARDAGEN Küchenmaß 5er-Satz - IKEA Deutschland](https://www.ikea.com/de/de/p/vardagen-kuechenmass-5er-satz-60324723)
- [How to convert 1 milliliter of table salt to grams](https://www.howmany.wiki/vw/--1--ml--of--table-salt--in--gram)

  - [Density Database Version 2.0 (2012) PDF](http://www.fao.org/3/ap815e/ap815e.pdf)