How should fruit be weighed for chutney?
Should chutney fruit be weighed prepared (peeled and cored) or weight of whole fruit?  Does it affect the end product.

Chutney means a lot of different things in different contexts. For the sort that's served immediately, it doesn't matter much. For the pickled sort, your recipe should indicate. But what are you making? Where are you getting your proportions from?

Generally, the recipe will tell you. 1 pound apples, peeled and cored, is not the same as 1 pound of peeled and cored apples. See also https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/37564/304

just a variety of regular chutney, not pickles...It's a summer staple for me.  I use fruit (right now peaches/necterines/plums/apricots), sugar, vinegar, onions, various spices etc.   Apples I usually peel/core, but I had a thought, as I was perusing a bunch of recipes for some spice variations, these soft fruits have hard 'stones' so removing reduces the prepared weight.  None of the dozen or so recipes I looked at indicate whether it's raw or peeled/de-stonedweight.  In the grand scheme, I'm thinking doesn't really matter as long as fruit/sugar/vinegar ratio is right.

Hi Kate...yes, as I don't use stoned fruit that often, it's only just occurred to me!

One comment explains the difference between

“[unit of measurement] fruit/vegetable, [method of processing]” = “weight/measure first, then prepare” and
“[unit of measurement>] [processed in a certain way] fruit/vegetable” = prep first, then measure.

This works reasonably well for English recipes. But not all culinary traditions and not all language patterns are the same. If the description in ingredient list is inconclusive, a good indicator is to read the instructions: if the recipe has a  a version of “peel / core / chop / remove x”, it’s probably the former. If not, I’d assume the latter, meaning previously prepped ingredients.
